# How to access the catch all route after ajax call failed while not changing URL with react-router

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redirect, react-router, http-status-code-404

I have a simple reactjs application which talks to a rest api and want it to serve the catch all route when the api returns a 404.

Since I'm using react-router-v4 I tried `this.props.history.push("/404");` which does serve the correct component but also changes the URL in der browser.
This change of the URL is what I don't want

I Have the following code

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Calendar}/>
                <Route path='/day/:number' component={Day}/>
                <Route component={Error404}/>
            </Switch>
        );
    }
}
```

and in Day.js I do something like

```
componentDidMount() {
    const dayNumber = parseInt(this.props.match.params.number);
    jQuery.ajax('http://localhost:9018/api/day/' + dayNumber)
        .done((result) => {
            this.setState({
                day: result
            });
        })
        .fail(() => {
            this.props.history.push("/404");
        });
}
```

So when I surf to a URL like `/no-match` the app renders the Error404 component while the URL stays on `/no-match` <- correct

When I surf to `/day/1` the app renders the Day component and backend returns `200`. URL stays at `/day/1` <- correct

When I surf to `/day/35` the app renders the Day component and backend returns `404`. Redirect renders Error404 component and URL changes to `/404` <- This I don't want.

So I get that pushing to history is probably wrong. 
But how can I implement a generalized solution that renders Error404 for every failed api call in the whole application?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the state 'status' depending on the result:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const dayNumber = parseInt(this.props.match.params.number);
    jQuery.ajax('http://localhost:9018/api/day/' + dayNumber)
        .done((result) => {
            this.setState({
                day: result, status: 'SUCCESS',
            });
        })
        .fail(() => {
            this.setState({ status: 'ERROR' })
        });
}
```

And then, in your rendering, you can show the component you like:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.status === 'SUCCESS' ? 'show day content' : 'show ErrorComponent'}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Depending on your whole app context [createMemoryHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory) from react-router might be worth a look as well, but from what I know it is only used for tests/native apps.

Comment: Ok that would work for the presented problem. But how about, when I have multiple Components doing the same, and when I extract ajax calls to another file. Could you think of a solution without depending on render method of the component?

Comment: So, having multiple Components doing the same is a bit weird, but I guess you mean multiple components that are calling an api endpoint? So, it actually is a good thing to not handle these requests in the components itself if you need to call them more often. (This rather asks for redux actions.) You then can create an error handler and render the error where you want - e.g. in your root component or in the component that uses the data requested. It totally depends on the use case, imo.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about multiple Components making API calls and how to generify error handling. I will take a look at redux. Thx!